# Typo3: How to disable Bootstrap Language Menu

Tags: typo3, multilingual, typo3-7.6.x

I installed the latest Typo 3 LTS 7 Version and used Bootstrap with it. I did not enable any multilanguage stuff, nor do I want it to be displayed. How to disable the language ("Deutsch, Dansk, English") which is presented after every footer?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found a solution.
Just add

```
page.theme.metasection.enable = 0
```

to the Template Constants.
This only disables the Language Footer.
I do not know however, how to configure it (i.e. replace the non existing language names like Dansk)

Answer (score -1):

The language menu is being built in EXT:bootstrap_package/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.txt (line 40).

```
lib.language = COA
lib.language {
    ...
}
```

It takes the languages you have defined in the backend (database), assigns information to these and builds up the HMENU. In the default bootstrap_package configuration's case that should be the languages with the ids 0,1,2.

```
lib.language.20.special.value = 0,1,2
```

You could change the values there, or get rid of the whole section all together (so not to load it at all) depending on what you want to achieve. If you want to remove it you need to remove the references in the template itself, too.

EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Partials/Page/Structure/Footer.html (line 21):

```
<div class="col-md-4 language">
    <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.language"/>
</div>
```

.. and from all other places you are referencing lib.language.